# How do I upload files to source?

Tags: file-upload, bitbucket

I've switched to windows and am having a hard time using bitbucket with it.

Within the downloads menu you can add files but this is not added to source.

I've also tried using source tree (web application) but when I attempt to push the files they do not exist in my directory. Any idea how I can do this or a guide which explains how to upload files.  It's been a number of years since I have used bitbucket on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket is simply a git provider. You'll have to use Git commands (or a GUI like Sourcetree, Gitkraken, etc.) to push (upload) your files to source.

A basic guide to working with Git can be found [here](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/).

Answer (score 1):

**Windows or Linux only you need a git console or git cli installed in your default cli.**

1. First clone your repository to your local system. Go to your
   bitbucket account and your repository need to be file uploaded. Copy
   the git url command. Open git console and type the following command.

> git clone "git URL"

2. Explore you repository and make changes. Like add file which you want to upload to it.
3. Go to your git console again and type the following commands.

> git add .
>
> git commit -m "commit message like - adding file"
>
> git push origin master